# Adding a refresh button to my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to add a Button at the top of my items, but i dont really know how implement it with my Base Adapter.

I have two lists headed by a textview, the problem I have is to implement a simple button on top of my two lists in order to create a refresh button, but I dont really know where insert this static button.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class ListSample_category3 extends Activity 
{

    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
    public final static String ITEM_COMPANY= "company";
    public final static String ITEM_DATE = "availabledate";

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String company, String date) 
    {
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
        item.put(ITEM_COMPANY, company);
        item.put(ITEM_DATE, date);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
        security.add(createItem("Remember passwords", "Cisco", "2012-02-10"));
        security.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Microsoft", "2012-02-10"));
        security.add(createItem("Show security warnings", "Apple", "2012-02-10"));

        // create our list and custom adapter
        SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

        adapter.addSection("Categorie 1", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item_category3, new String[] { "First item", "Item two" }));

        adapter.addSection("Categorie 2", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex_category3, 
            new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_COMPANY, ITEM_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_company, R.id.list_complex_date }));

        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.setContentView(list);

    }
}
```

My BaseAdapter

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header_category3);
    }

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) 
    {
        this.headers.add(section);
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) 
        {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section 
            if(position == 0) return section;
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
        int total = 0;
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
        return total;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
        int total = 1;
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
        return total;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) 
    {
        int type = 1;
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) 
        {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section 
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        int sectionnum = 0;
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section 
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            sectionnum++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

my 3 xml files:

```
<!-- list_header.xml -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />


<!-- list_item.xml -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />

<!-- list_complex.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_caption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

From this code i have 2 lists headed by a textview, the problem i have is to Implement a Simple button on top of my 2 lists in order to make refreshing (button), but on using this way i dont really know where insert this static button

Edit :

I tried to make an other xml file like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listpromo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i changed my activity to:

```
public class ListSample_category3 extends Activity 
{

    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
    public final static String ITEM_COMPANY= "company";
    public final static String ITEM_DATE = "availabledate";
    private ListView list;

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String company, String date) 
    {
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
        item.put(ITEM_COMPANY, company);
        item.put(ITEM_DATE, date);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
        security.add(createItem("Remember passwords", "Cisco", "2012-02-10"));
        security.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Microsoft", "2012-02-10"));
        security.add(createItem("Show security warnings", "Apple", "2012-02-10"));

        // create our list and custom adapter
        SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

        adapter.addSection("Categorie 1", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item_category3, new String[] { "First item", "Item two" }));

        adapter.addSection("Categorie 2", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex_category3, 
            new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_COMPANY, ITEM_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_company, R.id.list_complex_date }));

        // create ListView
        //ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listpromo);

        // OnItemClickListener on all items
        OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener()
        {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
              {

              }
        };
        list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.setContentView(list);

    }
}
```

But i have a NullPointerException :

08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.prixo/com.dev.prixo.OngletsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.prixo/com.dev.prixo.ListSample_category3}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-05 14:49:24.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2558): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.prixo/com.dev.prixo.ListSample_category3}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tell me how to do, please..

Comment: A question implies that you have done some research on your behalf. **What have you tried?** What specific problem are you encountering. Please learn your fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your design, your issue is that you are setting the contentView according to a ListView object:

```
ListView list = new ListView(this);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
this.setContentView(list);
```

which is a singular object, which is obviously going to cause a problem if you want to modify it and change the content of that particular Activity.

### My Suggestion

You need to create a layout xml file that you can set inside of your contentView. Specifically this xml would encompass:

```
Linearlayout<- orientation:veritcal
 <Button>
 <Listview>
 <Listview>
->
```

This layout would then be used in your setContentView and then you can retrieve the button and then configure its code to allow the refreshing of your ListViews. Or you could add it to your Options menu.

Comment: thanks Jox for your answer, i know that is the only one method to put a button, but i dont know how to do on my BaseAdapter class :? do you have an idea?

Comment: It has NOTHING to do with your base adapter, only your Activity.

Comment: Serious ??? i dont really know what i have to change, plus Jox can you just tell me , i'm blocked on my project.. :/

Comment: Create the XML layout file, apply it, attach a listener to the button. Have the button's execution code refresh the listviews by requerying and reassigning the adapter. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listpromo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Start Implement the refresh code for in your activity.

```
enter code here
Button refresh= (Button)findviewById(R.id.refresh);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       //Implement the List Adapter Code here to refresh the Content.
        }
    } );
```